# How to display Site Map on Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, navigation, site-settings

I have a Site with 5 Sub Sites. Now, in the sub site, I want the site map navigation to be displayed as below

[image: SiteMap Navigation]

Is there any way to get this site map on sub sites. Being new to Sharepoint, I am having difficulty on figuring what is the right option to get this done. Can anyone please suggest the solution.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no such settings to display site map on SharePoint Online sub sites. As a workaround, you could edit the global navigation to add parent site link.

1. Go to site settings-> Navigation.Change Global Navigation to Structural Navigation.

[image]

2. Then edit the global navigation link to add your parent site link:

[image]

Comment: When I do this, I'm getting edit option to update Tab section but not the sitemap navigation. Am I missing something here?

Comment: You didnot not miss anything. What you are editing is the global navigation instead of the sitemap navigation as I said. It is by design that the site map navigation can not be edited currently.